# Vue App, need styles to be added above other styles

Tags: vue.js

i'm integrating Vue into a website, however when I use a component it's styles are added just before the closing `</body>` tag, which is not ideal, as I need to add styles below these to over-ride colors etc, this is per client of course.

Is there a way I can add an `id` to my client styles, and have my component styles appended above here?

So at my document needs to look like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- Vue Styles -->
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <!-- END Vue Styles -->

    <!-- Client Styles -->
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <!-- END Client Styles -->

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use scoped styles for your vue app, that way the styles are contained to just your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can order the way styles are included. But there are a couple of things you can do.

- If you add styles via `import` in `App.js` they will be added first.
- You can use `!important` to your css definitions. Ofc this will only work if the initial definitions don't already have `!important` set.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't good then. I don't want to add `!important` on literally all the over-rides, as I can image they will be overwritten often, as each client might have their own color scheme or requests.

Comment: you could try to manually update the DOM and add a style tag with the desired link. It is ugly, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to try it out, but it seems that [CSS Extraction provided by the vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/extract-css.html#webpack-4) Webpack loader allows extracting the css to an external bundle. Once you have that, you can include it wherever you want on your webpage.

Comment: That would be good, however my component's are lazy loaded in, as we could have hundreds of them at some point but not all the websites will use them. What you suggested would bring in all the styles even if the component isn't there?

Comment: Like I said, I haven't used it, but I would think it brings all the styles. Is your css so big that this is really a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your application structure but in Vue you can add style for each component in that corresponding component.

TestComponent.vue

```
<template src='./Test.html'>
</template>
<script>
export default {
}
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: This is what I have, but of course that then gets appended to the DOM on load.